# Basic timeout for HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: python, session, redirect, flask, basic-authentication

I'm serving up a static file that to view requires a basic login and password. Currently I'm just using this snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/

right now it just stays active until the browser quits. I'd like to figure out how to write just a simple timeout. Something like "if its been 5 minutes, kill this and redirect the user back to the index page.

I'm pretty close, it times out, only thing is it remembers that redirect if the browser window is still open. Any suggestions on how to deal with that one last part? A cookie? Session clearing? Something else?

Thanks

```
def check_auth(username, password):
  #This function is called to check if a username / password combination is valid.
  return username == 'oneshot' and password == 'private'

def authenticate():
  # Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth
  return Response(
  'Could not verify your access level for that URL.\n'
  'You have to login with proper credentials', 401,
  {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

def requires_auth(f):
  @wraps(f)
  def decorated(*args, **kwargs):

    start_time = session.get('session_time', None)

    if start_time is None:
      start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
      session['session_time'] = start_time

    elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time

    if datetime.timedelta(0, 60, 0) < elapsed:
      return redirect(url_for('index'))


    auth = request.authorization
    if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
      return authenticate()

    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  return decorated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
def login_required(test):
  @wraps(test)
  def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'logged_in' in session:

      # session is always none
      start_time = session.get('session_time', None)


      #get the current time and set it as start time, this is also your session timer start
      if start_time is None:
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        session['session_time'] = start_time

      # make an end time 1 minute from now
      end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

      #find the current time in a for loop maybe? or just an if will probably work.
      if datetime.datetime.now() > end_time: 
        return redirect(url_for('expired', next=request.url))
        session.clear()
        start_time = session.get('session_time', None)

      return test(*args, **kwargs)
    else:

      return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
  return wrap


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():   
  error = None
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME']:
      error = 'Invalid username'
    elif request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
      error = 'Invalid password'
    else:
      session['logged_in'] = True
      return redirect(url_for('media'))
  return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/expired')
def expired():
  session.clear()
  return render_template('expired.html')
```